# Proper use of UseCallBack

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Currently, my code re-renders every time the query parameter is updated.  Once I remove the query parameter; however, I get a warning stating "React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'query'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps".  I have tried just defining my getData function within the useEffect, but I am using getData as on onclick function outside of the useEffect.  What I am trying to accomplish is to initially fetch articles on react hooks and then only fetch new data on submit as opposed to when the query is updated and not have any warnings about query being a missing dependency as well.  Any suggestions would help immensely.  the code is as follows:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react"
import axios from "axios"

const Home = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("react hooks")

  const getData = useCallback(async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=${query}`
    )
    setData(response.data)
  }, [query])

  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [getData])

  const handleChange = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setQuery(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type='text' onChange={handleChange} value={query} />
      <button type='button' onClick={getData}>
        Submit
      </button>
      {data &&
        data.hits.map(item => (
          <div key={item.objectID}>
            {item.url && (
              <>
                <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
                <div>{item.author}</div>
              </>
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: If you want to only run `getData` on submit, then you don't need `useEffect`, but if you do you could have a submitting state and only run the effect the `submitting` is true

Comment: sorry I want to initially fetch articles on react hooks but only fetch new data on submit as opposed to when the query is updated

Comment: @azium the only issue with your idea of the submitting state is I need the useEffect to initally run so I can populate the react hooks articles on mount

Comment: then set the submitting state to true initially. I can write up an answer for you in a moment

Comment: Can I see how you would do it? the issue I'm running into with the submitting state is that the data still updates as the query is updated.  I would really appreciate it @azium

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a `submitting` state as a condition for triggering your axios request

```
  const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(true)
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("react hooks")

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=${query}`
      )
      setData(response.data)
      setSubmitting(false) // call is finished, set to false
    }

    // query can change, but don't actually trigger 
    // request unless submitting is true

    if (submitting) { // is true initially, and again when button is clicked
      getData()
    }
  }, [submitting, query])

  const handleChange = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setQuery(event.target.value)
  }

  const getData = () => setSubmitting(true)
```

If you wanted to `useCallback`, it could be refactored as such:

```
  const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(true)
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("react hooks")

  const getData = useCallback(async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=${query}`
    )
    setData(response.data)
  }, [query])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (submitting) { // is true initially, and again when button is clicked
      getData().then(() => setSubmitting(false))
    }
  }, [submitting, getData])

  const handleChange = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setQuery(event.target.value)
  }
```

and in render

```
<button type='button' onClick={() => setSubmitting(true)}>
```

Comment: appears this solution isn't successfully fetching anything.  console log shows undefined for response.data

Comment: This code doesn't change anything about the way you make queries. make sure the network request is correct?

Comment: oh sorry, I missed the async keyword, try again

Comment: I figured it out it was because of the await outside of an async request.  This appears to have done the trick! thanks @azium this makes a lot more sense

Comment: updated the answer to match your question with useCallback

Comment: Wasn't the question about UseCallBack?

Comment: @GN it is. do you have another question? You could make one and link it here if you like