# How to pass a fetched object from App.js to a child component asynchronously in ReactJS v16+

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

### TL;DR

How to pass a fetched object from App.js to a child component asynchronously?

Do I have to wait for the whole data to be fetched and then return App.js? If so, How?

---

I'm trying to create a dashboard with react-chartjs-2 where it fetches data from the server as a whole object, however the chart loads before the fetching process, here's the code:

```
import './App.css';
import AvgVisitDuration from './component/AvgVisitDuration';
import Devices from './component/Devices';
import About from './component/About';

let stats;
let devices = [];

async function getStats() {
  const response = await fetch('http://192.168.1.4:8080/api');
  const data = response.json();
  stats = data;
  getDevices();
}

function getDevices() {
    // Set 'devices' as a new array based on 'stats'
}

function App() {
  getStats();
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <About />
      <AvgVisitDuration />
      <Devices Data={devices} /> // This is the chart component
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

here we have stats as the fetched object and extracted some of the information (like stats.isMobile) into a new array called devices.
but the problem here is that when I pass the devices variable as props to `<Devices />` component it only returns an empty array (the one which is first declared.)

I'll be grateful if you could tell me there is any other approach for this.

Comment: This may be the thing you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60835660/proper-use-of-usecallback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a lot about React fundamentals and you should go read the docs which have plenty of examples and patterns. What you want to do is make sure your component can handle a "loading" state. Async requests are not immediate and take time, what is your component going to look like while you wait for the request to complete ?

I am using a state variable to track the completion of the request. I would recommend looking up how useEffect works as well to better understand this snippet.

```
import AvgVisitDuration from './component/AvgVisitDuration';
import Devices from './component/Devices';
import About from './component/About';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';


function App() {
  const [devices, setDevices] = useState([])
  const [loadingDevices, setLoadingDevices] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getStats() {
      setLoadingDevices(true)
      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://192.168.1.4:8080/api');
        const data = response.json();
        const transformData = ... // do whatever you need to do to extract the data you need from the async call
        setDevices(transformData)
        setLoadingDevices(false)
      } catch(e) {
        setLoadingDevices(false)
      }
    }

    getStats();
  }, [setStats, setLoadingDevices])

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <About />
      <AvgVisitDuration />
      {loadingDevices ? <div>loading ...</div> : <Devices Data={devices} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```